# UItableView Cell Content size for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Hi I face the strange problem.

I have created UITableView for iPad.

When I check the cell width i found it's 320 but for iPad i need 768 and 1024.

The below screen shows the TableView in which the cell shows in Table

When I add scrollBar with following `UIScrollView *previewScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 250)];`

```
 NSLog(@"cell.contentView.frame.size.widt  %f",cell.contentView.frame.size.width);
```

the scrollbar shows only 320 width(**cell.contentView.frame.size.width**) area.
what should i do for set the iPad size cell content view

[image: screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use autoResizingFlags correctly. On creation, the cell is only 320px width, but on display it will be larger.

Try this, when creating your scrollview:
`previewScrollView.autoresizingFlags = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`

This should work, but when you even need more control, you can still use the tableView delegate method: `tableView:willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:`

Comment: For me on the iPad, willDisplayCell is still reporting 320.

Comment: @BillCheswick in this case check your overall setup. Probably the tableView itself or its superview has the wrong bounds.

Comment: No, the tableView knows its own size.  I am disappointed that contentView doesn't know its size, and am switching to a custom cell view.